# How many wards do I have to use to make sightstones efficient?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that wards are extremely important in League of Legends, and I know that often, people like to buy the sightstone. However, many times I go for straight up wards instead. The sightstone is not used enough, in my opinion, to be more beneficial than the cost of buying that wards themselves.

This may be because I am in bronze 2, but I am just wondering, how many wards do you actually need to use (and, how many times do you need to go back) for the sightstone to be worth it? I need to know, because if you have to go back so many times that you lose about 2 levels compared to your lane opponents, I will just buy regular wards.

Comment: Well.. sightstone = 950g. Green wards = 75g. 950/75 = 14.5 wards. Assuming you use all 4 wards before backing, it takes at least 4 backs.

Comment: ^^ doesn't take into account the gold value of the health from sightstone, though I'm not sure if that's really relevant to the askers question :) Just looked at the wiki, it actually has a good segment on effeciency http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sightstone

Comment: I'd like to note that in general, you should consider Sightstone as a source of *temporary* wards, like a cheap, short-ranged, short-cooldown Clairvoyance. You should still be using Sight Wards as your primary form of permanent vision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sightstone costs 950g. It gives you 180 health, the same as the ruby crystal that goes into creating it. Assuming the ruby crystal is of value to you, that means you have 950g-475g=475g invested in the warding portion of the sightstone alone. If that health isn't of value to you, or you would not have gotten a ruby crystal, then you should really not discount (all of) the ruby crystal's price.

This means you have somewhere between 475g (best case) and 950g (worst case, because you don't value HP at all) invested in the sight stone.

Green wards cost 75g. 475/75 = 6.33 wards. 950/75 = 12.67 wards.

In general, if you use it **7** or more times (meaning going back once after you buy), you've probably made back your cost. If you don't value health much, think of it more like 10 uses to break even (go back twice). If you don't value health at all, 13 uses (go back three times).

As a further consideration, remember that you can sell it back later in the game, if this turns out to be useful for you. This could reduce the number of wards you consider your "break even" point, especially if you don't value the health from the item. If you had bought an equivalent number of wards, you would not be able to recoup the sell price of the sightstone later in the game (380g)

EDIT: With regards to upgrading, the sightstone only upgrades into the ruby sightstone. This adds the effect of an additional ruby crystal for MORE than the price of a ruby crystal (price of crystal + cost to combine). While this is a useful thing if you're out of item slots and have gold to upgrade, it doesn't really apply to situations where you'd be worried about efficiency. It does allow you to have more charges (5 instead of 4) so you wouldn't have to back as often, and as pointed out in the comments allows 3 simultaneous ward placements.

Along the lines of upgrading, when/if you get to the point of the game where inventory slots are at a premium, keep in mind that this allows you to have wards+health in one slot, instead of having a slot reserved just for wards.

Comment: what about upgrading the sightstone?? when you get 5 slots and just add the combination cost? (health is always helpful ;))

Comment: keep in mind this also allows to place one more ward

Comment: Having a ruby sightstone allows you to have 3 active wards on the map at the same time, as opposed to 2 active with the basic sightstone.

Comment: If you've read about the upcoming changes for Season 4, you know that all of this will be changing soon.

Comment: I agree with the maths but I can't agree with the term of "not valuing HP at all". I don't want to generalize , but you usually get sightstone as support (or Lee Sin ^_^) and on the most supports early HP are really valuable (especially on Sona and squshiy supports like her). So even if you were not planning on buying a ruby stone it's still from great value to you in the laning phase.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't -- I'm just saying how much you value it is variable person-to-person, and here are the upper and lower limits. **IF** you don't value HP at all, here's what it's worth. **IF** you value HP at the rate given by ruby crystal, here's what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

If a ward placed prevents or nets your team even **1 death/kill**, the sightstone has paid for itself, imo. Keep this in mind as League is not really a game about min/max NECESSARILY, so much as "winning continually." If you win early game, it's very easy to win mid game, etc. If wards let you do this, it doesn't matter if they're mathematically cost-effective. I know you're looking for the math, but I feel like this point HAS to be made.

Answer (score 0):

With the new season 4 changes, sightstone is more worth it. You'll give yourself a slight needed bit of tankiness as support, as well as totally satisfy your 3 ward limit the rest of the game without needing to worry about overwriting existing wards (since you're not actually paying the cost per ward).

Comment: Hi Zero, welcome to Arqade. This is a Q&A site rather than a discussion forum, and so you may find that this gets downvoted.  One reason is that answers do not necessary stay in the order that they are made. Your comment would be better made as a Comment on the Answer that you are responding to. I realise that you can't leave comments at present, but if you stick around and ask and answer questions, that privilege comes pretty quickly. Happy Christmas :-)